# How to extend class form SharedCode module in Swift?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created open class `GitHubApiClient` in `SharedCode` module `kotlin-multiplatform`. When I extend this class in Android app it works fine, but when I want to extend class in IOS app I have an error:
[image]

In the `SharedCode` module class is open:

[image]

In Xcode class `GitHubApiClient` looks like this:

[image]

How I can fix this problem? I need that this class will be open in Xcode too.
I use `kotlin_coroutines version 1.3.0` `ktor version 1.2.4` and `kotlin serialization version 0.12.0`

Comment: Hello! Please provide additional info on the kotlin and kotlin/native versions. Also, it would be helpful to know more about the class structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `private` to `open` in GithubApiClient constructor.